# Meaning of XMM register values shown in Visual Studio debugger's register window

Tags: visual-studio, sse, visual-studio-debugging, cpu-registers

I am finding it hard to interpret the value of xmm registers in the register window of Visual Studio. The windows displays the following :

```
XMM0 = 00000000000000004018000000000000 XMM1 = 00000000000000004020000000000000 
XMM2 = 00000000000000000000000000000000 XMM3 = 00000000000000000000000000000000 
XMM4 = 00000000000000000000000000000000 XMM5 = 00000000000000000000000000000000 
XMM6 = 00000000000000000000000000000000 XMM7 = 00000000000000000000000000000000 

XMM00 = +0.00000E+000      XMM01 = +2.37500E+000      XMM02 = +0.00000E+000      
XMM03 = +0.00000E+000      XMM10 = +0.00000E+000      XMM11 = +2.50000E+000      
XMM12 = +0.00000E+000      XMM13 = +0.00000E+000
```

From the code that I am running, the value of XMM0 and XMM1 should be 6 and 8 (or other way round). The register value here shown is : `XMM01 = +2.37500E+000`

What does this translate to ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it looks like:

```
XMM0 = { 6.0, 0.0 }  // 6.0 = 0x4018000000000000 (double precision)
XMM1 = { 8.0, 0.0 }  // 8.0 = 0x4020000000000000 (double precision)
```

The reason you are having problems interpreting this is that your debugger is only displaying each 128 bit XMM register in hex and then below that as 4 x *single* precision floats, but you are evidently using *double* precision floats.

I'm not familiar with the Visual Studio debugger, but there should ideally be a way to change the representation of your XMM registers - you may have to look at the manual or online help for this.

Note that in general using double precision with SSE is rarely of any value, particularly if you have a fairly modern x86 CPU with two FPUs.

Comment: if someone stumbles upon this via Google like I did. The doubles are in `XMM0DL`, `XMM0DH` in the visual studio debugger which are shown in the "registers" dialog with "AVX Double" enabled.

Comment: If someone wants to see them in VS2017+ (I think, I'm using VS2019) you have to use the watch window and you can add `XMM0` with pop-down or get specific `XMM0.m128_f64` or get more specific `XMM0.m128_f64[1]`

Comment: *Note that in general using double precision with SSE is rarely of any value, particularly if you have a fairly modern x86 CPU with two FPUs.* - This is not accurate.  For pure vertical problems that don't need shuffling, `mulpd` / `addpd` give you twice the throughput of scalar, if you're not bottlenecked on memory bandwidth (e.g. data hot in L2 or L1d cache.)  2/clock `mulpd` is twice as much work per cycle as 2/clock `mulsd`; the back end can't schedule separate `mulsd` instructions to separate halves of the same SIMD multiplier unit.